# Can a body with angular retardation proportional to angular velocity ever stop rotating?

Tags: integration, rotational-kinematics

I was attempting a rotational mechanics question where it was mentioned that:

> Due to friction about the axis, the wheel experiences an angular retardation proportional to its angular velocity. If its angular velocity falls to half while it makes *n* rotations, how many more rotations will it make before coming to rest?

I was writing differential equations for this (they turned out to be very similar to first-order chemical kinetics):

$$\omega = \omega_0e^{-kt}, \alpha = -k\omega$$ (where $k$ is a positive constant)

This doesn't make sense with the idea of angular velocity ever being zero, for if it does become zero then $e^{-kt}$ would have to become zero, which is not possible.

Am I making any conceptual/physical integration mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you have an expression of the form $\omega(t)=\omega_0e^{-k\,t}$ then Mathematically, when $t\to \infty$ the $\omega\to 0$, and so $\omega$ would never reach zero in a finite time.

However, in the real world it is often the case that the final value of $\omega$ has to be (significantly) smaller than the initial value $\omega_0$.
Then the decision has to be made as to what is meant by *significantly smaller*.

For example you might consider the final value being one percent of the initial value as sufficiently small, ie $0.01 = e^{-kt_{1\%}} \Rightarrow t_{1\%} \approx 4.6/k. $

In the case of radioactive decay, the time to reach $1\%$ of the original activity would be $0.01 = \left(\frac 12 \right)^n \Rightarrow n\approx 6.6$ where $n$ is the number of half lives.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider the negative sign in the exponent of e. So I can't solve this for t, but'll have to use velocity and displacement instead.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if it has the angular *velocity* $\omega(t)=\omega_0 e^{-kt}$, the total amount of rotation will be $\theta=\int_0^\infty \omega(t) dt= \omega_0 / k$.

Comment: This is a nice point.